# How to show/hide menus using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu with menu items that are only being showed when they are clicked. To hide them again they have to be clicked again. That's all good, but I also need to hide other visible menu items when another menu item is clicked.

Im currently using:

```
$(this).parent().find("element").toggle();
```

So if menu item 2 is visible and menu item 1 is clicked, menu item 2 needs to hide again and menu item 1 needs to be visible.
How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide/show elements on click:

```
$('.menu-item').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.show();
    $this.parent().children('.menu-item').not($this).hide();
});
```

Use find instead of children depending on nesting.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$('.submenu').hide();
$('.menuitem').click(function() {
  var thissubmenu = $(this).find('.submenu');   
  $('.submenu').not(thissubmenu).hide();
  $(this).find(".submenu").toggle();
});
​
```

I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cYUXP/3), which I think does what you're looking for.

But maybe someone knows a more elegant way.